# Create a loop to run and store the r.stats output of several viewsheds?

Tags: grass-gis, python-2.7, loop, viewshed, grass.script

I have 15 viewsheds (view 0-14) from which I would like to export the cell count. I can do this for one viewshed through:

```
count=[]
i=0

viewshedSize=grass.read_command("r.stats", overwrite=True,flags="c", input="view0")
countsperline= viewshedSize.split("\n")
count.append(type(float(countsperline[1].split(" ")[1])))
```

How can I run a loop to do this for each viewshed?

Comment: Hi New Contributor. It looks like you are asking how to write a `for loop` in Python? I'm not certain, but if so, the question is better asked on a different site, and the answer is `for i in range(13):` And then in the loop maybe replace `"view0"` with `"view"+str(i)`

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help. Will try another site for future python related questions

Comment: See here: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/r.viewshed.cva.html for a Python implementation of cumulative viewsheds:  r.viewshed.cva undertakes a "cumulative viewshed analysis" using a vector points map as input "viewing" locations, using r.viewshed to calculate the individual viewsheds.